# replacement capacitors - picture attached this time

Tags: capacitor

https://photos.app.goo.gl/Auk8US8urgpGgjfK6
[image]
Not sure if the picture is visible - if not please ignore posting!
These are the capacitors I want to replace but I don't know what type they are.

Comment: Mike Collier - Hi, This is a continuation of your (active) question [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/529447/replacement-capacitors) so this really should have been an edit to *that* question (where you also give context that is missing here). Please add these images to *that* question using the "edit" link on *that* question, and then delete *this* question. Thanks.

Comment: Mike Collier - Hi, Another member has kindly added your photo from here, into your previous question. Therefore the only action you need to take now, is to delete this question as it adds no value and the topic is continuing in your previous question. (If you are using a desktop browser, you should see a link marked "delete" near the ones "share", "edit" etc. If you are using a mobile phone/tablet then the "delete" link might not be visible. In that case either use a real desktop browser, or switch your mobile browser into "desktop view", so you can click the "delete" link.) Thanks.